# How to understand this nested recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

This code has me lost. When run, it outputs sequences which I finds strange:

```
def print_n(number):
    if (number <= 0):
         return None
    else:
         print number
         print_n(number-1)
    print_n(number-1)

print_n(4)
```

I thought it would output this sequence:

> 4,3,2,1,1,2,1,3,2,1

however it actually outputs:

> 4,3,2,1,1,2,1,1,3,2,1,1,2,1,1

I tried to draw the stack diagram of this function but when I get lost at the second appearance of the `print_n(number-1)`.

I can understand this program without the second appearance of the `print_n(number-1)`, as it's just normal recursion. However, the second `print_n(number-1)`, seems much more complicated than I expected, I don't know how to trace this function call and explain the result...

Answer (score 7):

Since the `if` block has an unconditional return, you can remove the `else` and the program will continue to behave the same way.

```
def print_n(number):
    if (number <= 0):
        return None
    print number
    print_n(number-1)
    print_n(number-1)
```

Here, it's more apparent what is going on: You print number, and then call `print_n` twice using `number-1`. You can work backwards to derive the output.

- `print_n(1)` prints "1"
- `print_n(2)` prints "2" plus "1" plus "1": "211"
- `print_n(3)` prints "3" plus "211" plus "211": "3211211"
- `print_n(4)` prints "4" plus "3211211" plus "3211211": "432112113211211"

Comment: You can see the recursion [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+print_n(number)%3A%0A++++if+(number+%3C%3D+0)%3A%0A+++++++++return+None%0A++++else%3A%0A+++++++++print+number%0A+++++++++print_n(number-1)%0A++++print_n(number-1)%0A%0Aprint_n(4)&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0)

Answer (score 1):

I liked the answer of Kevin, but let me add a few words towards "understanding recursion":

I often suggest using sheets of paper representing the stack. each sheet contains its local varaibles and current state - and you can mark the line you are "processing" with a pen.

Use a separate sheet as output / console.

This gives you a very good understanding of what is going on.

Of course, following your code in a debugger and examining the stack trace can be helpful as well. But try the paper-approach first!